# console.log looping json data but display not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to display json data on the page, however when sending the output to html it only displays the last id.

When using `console.log` it loops through each id available but not on the page output itself

```
var username = $("#usernameinfo").text();

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "<?= base_url()?>"+"account/listings/more_user_ads",
    data: {
        "username": username,
        "pid": "<?=$this->input->get('pid')?>"
    },
    success: function(res){
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
            var output = "";
            var object = res[i];

            output = "<p>" + object.id + "</p>";
            $("#tg-authoradsslider").html(output);
            // outputs only the id of 3 which is the last id in the loop

            console.log(output);
            /* consoles.logs 
            <p>1</p>
            <p>2</p>
            <p>3</p>*/
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`.html()` remove older data and paste new data. that's why you are getting the last record only

use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
for (var i=0;i<res.length;i++){
    var object = res[i];
    var output = "<p>"+object.id+"</p>";
    $("#tg-authoradsslider").append(output);
}
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
var res = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 }
];

for (var i=0;i<res.length;i++){
  var object = res[i];
  var output = "<p>"+object.id+"</p>";
  $("#tg-authoradsslider").append(output);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tg-authoradsslider"></div>
```

Comment: chris keenan  did you checked my answer?

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems.

1. You re-initialize `output` in each iteration setting it back to an empty string.
2. You replace the content in HTML on each iteration so only the final one is shown.

Make the changes below to fix these issues:

**Change**

```
for (var i=0;i<res.length;i++){
    var output ="";
    var object = res[i];
    output = "<p>"+object.id+"</p>";
    $("#tg-authoradsslider").html(output);
}
```

**To**

```
var output ="";
for (var i=0;i<res.length;i++){
    var object = res[i];
    output += "<p>"+object.id+"</p>";
}
$("#tg-authoradsslider").html(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop:

Include these in your code
1. `Template literals`
2. use `append` instead of html

```
let output ="";
for (let i=0;i<res.length;i++){
    let object = res[i];
    output += `<p>${object.id}</p>`;
}
$("#tg-authoradsslider").append(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery, just take advantage of some of the built in functionality already there.

```
success: function(res){
    var author = $("#tg-authoradsslider");
    res.forEach( r => author.append($("<p>").text(r.id)) );
}
```

Here is a quick demo using a mocked environment

```js
var res = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 }
];

var author = $("#tg-authoradsslider");
res.forEach( r => author.append($("<p>").text(r.id)) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tg-authoradsslider"></div>
```